# How to set default value for Active Choices Reactive Parameter plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using the following Groovy code snippet for listing all the git branches in particular git repo and I can get that list successfully. But how can I set a default value for this list ? I'm trying to set **master** as default value.

```
def gettags = ("git ls-remote --heads git@org/sample-repo-service.git").execute()
def repoNameList = gettags.text.readLines().collect {
    it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use the option selected for the default value `'master:selected'` and then return the list.

```
def gettags = ("git ls-remote --heads git@github.com:org/sample-repo-service.git").execute()
def repoNameList = gettags.text.readLines().collect {
    it.split()[1].replaceAll('refs/heads/', '').replaceAll('refs/tags/', '').replaceAll("\\^\\{\\}", '')
}
repoNameList.add(0, 'master:selected')
return repoNameList
```